# Tkinter stringvar dropdown menu

Tags: python, string, user-interface, tkinter

I have three dropdown menus and 3 string variables that will take on the value of the menus, However in the function that I define query, it seems as if the string variables do not take on the value each time I select a new one on the dropdown menu. It will print the set value and do nothing else.  Also what's weird is that it was working perfectly and then suddenly didn't work at all.

Really need help on this one thanks.

```
root=Tk()
root.title('Query')
root.geometry('600x400')
def query():
    print(clicked_id_mouse.get())
    print(clicked_id_filename.get())
    print(clicked_id_researcher.get())

clicked_id_mouse=StringVar()
clicked_id_mouse.set("Choose Mouse Id")
drop_mouse= OptionMenu(root,clicked_id_mouse,*mouse_id)
drop_mouse.place(x=50,y=150)


clicked_id_researcher=StringVar()
clicked_id_researcher.set("Choose Researcher")
researcher= OptionMenu(root,clicked_id_researcher,*r_i)
researcher.place(x=200,y=150)



clicked_id_filename=StringVar()
clicked_id_filename.set("Choose Filename")
filename= OptionMenu(root,clicked_id_filename,*filename)
filename.place(x=350,y=150)
button= Button(root,text="Query",command=query())
button.place(x=210,y=200)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are assigning a command to a button use "lambda: ...". Otherwise it will execute it only once the button is created. Your code should work as intended by changing

```
button= Button(root,text="Query",command=query())
```

into

```
button= Button(root,text="Query",command=lambda: query())
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: `command=query` works just as well and is a bit simpler.